# Scala case class: how to validate constructor's parameters

Tags: scala

Here below is a **case class** that verifies the `name` parameter is neither `null` nor empty:

```
case class MyClass(name: String) {

    require(Option(name).map(!_.isEmpty) == Option(true), "name is null or empty")
}
```

As expected, passing `null` or an empty string to `name` results in an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Is it possible to rewrite the validation to get either `Success` or `Failure` instead of throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't have a constructor return something else than the class type. You can, however, define a function on the companion object to do just that:

```
case class MyClass private(name: String)

object MyClass {  
  def fromName(name: String): Option[MyClass] = {
    if(name == null || name.isEmpty)
      None
    else 
      Some(new MyClass(name))
  }
```

You can of course return a `Validation`, an `Either` or a `Try` if you prefer.

Comment: I am hitting the same area; validating case class parameters. I just posted something about it on StackOverflow's sister site, CodeReview. If you have time to look it over, I would appreciate any feedback you might have on it; i.e. help reducing boilerplate, better methods for approaching the problem space, etc.: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60645/reducing-boilerplate-when-validating-parameters-and-using-a-tuple-for-the-parame

Comment: The downside to this is that the object can become in an invalid state by someone calling the copy method on the case class

Comment: if not valid then None does not explain why

Comment: @ses as per my final line "You can of course return a Validation, an Either or a Try if you prefer." Any of these types can be used to provide more information regarding the failure.

Comment: Not sure what is going on here, but this cannot compile. Compiler won't know which apply method to match to - the one generated by the case class, or the one you defined here. You can create an object with a different name - but using the same name does not work.

Comment: @DanGordon - Good point.  I'm a bit confused, because I'm almost positive at the time I wrote this response the compiler would allow you to do that.  The `apply` in the companion object was overriding the one auto-generated by the case class.  I may be wrong though.  Anyway, I changed the name of the function in the object.  Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Wait isn't this still incorrect? I was thinking that the object needs to be called something else. So the object definition would be something like, `object MyC {`, and you would still have an `apply` method. I actually did something like that to make object instantiation a lot easier. For example, your class has a long name like `SuperLongClassNameForShapes`, and then I name the object `MyShape`. That way I can create a new object using this syntax: `val aShape = MyShape(...)`, and it returns a instance of `SuperLongClassNameForShapes`

Comment: No, the object has to have the same name as the class to be considered a companion object, and have access to the private constructor.  The problem you pointed at (at least, the one I found when trying the code locally with latest scala) is that the case class already implicitly defines an `apply` with the same signature in addition to the one I suggested. So the compiler raised an error, saying that you can't have 2 `def apply(s: String)` functions in the same object.

Comment: I've found that marking the constructor private on a case class does nothing to protect users from instantiating without the `new` keyword. I.e. people can still instantiate by calling `MyClass("somename")`. This kind of breaks everything in this solution.